# Proof of a expression for a sum

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, induction, binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to prove that for all $k=2,3,...$, $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} {k-1 \choose i}\frac{(-1)^i}{i+1}=\frac{1}{k}-1$.

My idea is use induction in $k$, and use the fact that ${k \choose i}=\frac{k}{k-i}{k-1 \choose i}=\frac{k}{i}{k-1 \choose i-1}$, but I think that this path doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? Did you try and got stuck?

Comment: Yes, I tried and got stuck. On the other hand, I think that the expression is true only for low $k$.

Comment: Multiply through by $k$, and then use the index shift $j = i+1$. Something familiar should appear.

Comment: You can also write $\sum_\limits{i=0}^k {k \choose i}\frac{(-1)^i}{i+1}=\frac{1}{k+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\binom{k-1}i\frac{(-1)^i}{i+1}&\overset{(1)}=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\binom{k}{i+1}\frac{(-1)^i}k\\
&=\frac1k\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\binom{k}{i+1}(-1)^i\\
&=\frac1k\left(\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}i(-1)^{i+1}+\binom{k}0-\binom{k}1\right)\\
&=\frac1k\left(1-k-\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}i(-1)^i\right)\\
&\overset{(2)}=\frac1k\left(1-k-(1-1)^k\right)\\
&=\frac1k-1
\end{align*}$$

Equality $(1)$ uses the identity $\frac1{k+1}\binom{n}k=\frac1{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k+1}$, and $(2)$ uses the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 0):

(I apologize in advance for my English level.)

Your assumptions about the solution are correct, I will try to illustrate their implementation in detail.

Let's try to simplify the expression for the sum to Newton's binomial formula. Newton's binomial formula looks like:
$$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} x^{n-k} y^k$$

Rewritу the sum (let $n = k-1$):
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \binom{k-1}{i} \frac{(-1)^i}{i+1} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \binom{n}{i} \frac{(-1)^i}{i+1} = -1 + 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \binom{n}{i} \frac{(-1)^i}{i+1} = -1 + \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} \frac{(-1)^i}{i+1}$$

Let:
$$S = -1 + \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} \frac{(-1)^i}{i+1}$$

Multiply both sides on $n+1$:
$$(n+1)S = -(n+1)+(n+1)\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} \frac{(-1)^i}{i+1} = -(n+1)+\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} \frac{(-1)^i (n+1)}{i+1}$$

Using the fact that:
$$\frac{n+1}{i+1} \binom{n}{i} = \binom{n+1}{i+1}$$

We can rewrite the sum:
$$(n+1)S = -(n+1)+\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} \frac{(-1)^i (n+1)}{i+1} = -(n+1)+\sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^i \binom{n+1}{i+1} = -(n+1)-\sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^{i+1} \binom{n+1}{i+1} = -(n+1)-\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} (-1)^{i} \binom{n+1}{i} = 1 - (n+1) - \sum_{i=0}^{n+1} (-1)^{i} \binom{n+1}{i}$$

Now, let's use Newton's binomial formula:
$$(n+1)S = 1 - (n+1) - \sum_{i=0}^{n+1} (-1)^{i} \binom{n+1}{i} = 1 - (n+1) - (1-1)^{n+1}=1-(n+1)$$

As the final step, we will divide both sides by $n+1$ and do the reverse substitution ($k=n+1$):
$$(n+1)S = 1 - (n+1)$$
$$S = \frac{1}{n+1} - 1 = \frac{1}{k}-1$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \binom{k-1}{i} \frac{(-1)^i}{i+1} = \frac{1}{k} - 1$$

Answer (score 0):

By Binomial theory we have
$$1+\sum_{i=1}^n {n \choose i}(-1)^i x^i= (1-x)^n.$$
Integrate wit r. t. $x$ from $x=0$ t0 $x=1$, we get
$$x+\sum_{i=1}^n {n \choose i} (-1)^i \frac{x^{i+1}}{i+1}|_{0}^{1}=-\frac{(1-x)^{n+1}}{n+1}|_{0}^{1}$$
$$\implies 1+\sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^i \frac{{n \choose i}}{i+1}=\frac{1}{n+1}$$
$$\implies \sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^i \frac{{n \choose i}}{i+1}=\frac{1}{n+1}-1$$
Finally put $n=k-1$ as per the question here we get
$$\implies \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} (-1)^i \frac{{k-1 \choose i}}{i+1}=\frac{1}{k}-1$$